# Update Firestore objects of one collection if the object of another collection is deleted?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

can anyone help me - I believe with the basic thing. I would like to have object of `products` collection which will keep UID’s of possible objects of `components` collection. I want to achieve that if I will delete a `component` object with specific UID, this ID will be deleted in all `product` objects which owned this component.

```
{
  ...
  components: [
    95Wzk5SLn5NVYWFTG11GrbiJCCG3,
    dsafk5SLn5NVYWFTG11GrbiJCCda,
    32424234kkj243jh23j4h2kj34h2,
  ]
}

delete -> /components/95Wzk5SLn5NVYWFTG11GrbiJCCG3
```

What is the easiest way to do that?

Should I use google functions for this thing?

Comment: If you have hard time with which you believe is a basic thing, it's time for you to read the product documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Asdfg. I have already done that but I didn't find an answer. A lot of things are not covered in Firestore documentation despite that, I see that there is high demand for them - e.g. if I am looking for help in unofficial sources.

Comment: did you tried trigger function..!?

Comment: Can you show the entire data model? How do you store the `products` objects?

Comment: thank you @pepe it seems like triggers will be helpful in this case!